# Algorithm to determine if a rational fraction has only non negative coefficients

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, power-series, rational-functions

Is there an algorithm that takes as input a polynomial in two variables $P \in \mathbb{N}[x,y]$ and outputs YES if and only if the coefficients of the series $\frac{1}{1-(x+y)} - \frac{1}{1-P}$ are non negative integers?

Comment: That seems really, really specific, so I would claim that even if someone had such an algorithm lying around somewhere, they would most likely not publish it; unless of course this problem has relevant applications, if yes feel free to share them. If you give some more information (e.g. what coefficients, of $x^iy^j$ or a different basis; or: what if $P = 1$ or other cases that might cause problems), someone might be able to point you towards a general approach that can be applied here.

Comment: Yes, for P =/= 1 and in the basis $x^i y^j$. I agree that my question is on a specific case, but I wonder if there exists some more general algorithms that can be implied for this case.
Meanwhile, I found that the general statement (for any rational fraction) seems to be an open problem:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13342/what-characterizes-rational-functions-with-nonnegative-integer-taylor-coefficien So I guess that the answer to my question is "unknown".

Comment: Do you mean the Taylor series centred at $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

Comment: Yes! So for example, the coefficient of $x^i y^j$ in $\frac{1}{1-(x+y)}$ is the binomial coefficient ${i+j \choose i}$.